# Proving by induction that for $m, n\in\omega$ and $m < n$ ,then there exists a $p$ s.t. $n=m+p^+$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, set-theory

I am in a set theory class working with the natural numbers, where $\omega$ represents the natural numbers and $n^+=n\cup\{n\}$ is the successor of $n$ for all $n\in\omega$. The book we use is Enderton. Also, we define addition by recursion:
\begin{align}
+:{}&\omega \times \omega \rightarrow\omega \\
&m+0=m \\
&m+n^+=(m+n)^+.
\end{align}

Also, we have that $m ∈ n$ iff $m < n$. Further another theorem states that if $m,n,p\in\omega$ then $m<n$ iff $m+p<n+p$.

The question I am asked to solve, by induction, reads:

> Suppose that $m, n\in\omega$ and that $m < n$. Then there exists $p\in\omega$ such
>   that $n = m + p^+$.

Now I need help setting up my set and deciding how for the inductive step when we pick $n\in S$ this helps with finding $n^+$ in the set. I want to use induction on $n$.

I was thinking:

Let $S=\{m,n\in\omega\mid m < n \text{ and there exists }p\in\omega\text{ such that }n=m+p^+\}$. Then $0$ is in the set because nothing is smaller then $0$. The to show that $n^+$ is in the set I am not sure how I would start. What variables would I fix?

Or I was thinking of starting by saying let $m, n\in\omega$ and that $m < n$. Then let the set $S=\{p\in\omega\mid n=m+p^+\}$. Then again starting with showing $0$ is in the set.

Comment: What is the definition of < or  of <=?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Whay do you mean? In terms of the relationship between m and n?

Comment: @sam in axioms you have been given for natural numbers how has < been defined?

Comment: @QthePlatypus I have added this information into my question.

Comment: The first S does not make sense.  The second S is either empty or a singleton depending upon n,m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do the induction it s better that the set S you take contains only one kind of element. So what you first considered as $S=\{m, n \in \omega$ and $m<n | \exists p \in \omega s.t m=n+p^{+}  \}$ would not work so easilly as you imply that you re doing induction on both m and n at the same time. The second set you considered will also not work as the statement does not hold for every p. What you can do is induction on m alone, or n alone. Preferably n. So consider $S=\{n\in \omega$ s.t for every $m<n \exists p |$ $n=m+p^+ \}$ Then for n=0 it s obviously true , and if it stands for n, then you need to show that for every $m<n^+$ you can find such a p. However $m<n^+$ means that either $m=n$ or $m<n$ and i think you can continue the rest yourself. Hope this helps!

Comment: I actually modified my set by saying first fix $m\in\omega$ then $S$={ $n\in\omega$ | for any $m<n$ there exists $p\in\omega$ such that $n= m+ p^+$}.

Comment: Could I use transitivity instead to show $m<n^+$?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly. You dont have to show or prove that $m<n^+$, that s your hypothesis. All you re saying is that IF $m<n^+$ then you need to show that the proposition holds. And you do that by taking the case that m=n and the case that m<n and proving each of those independetly

Answer (score 0):

Prove if m < 0, then some p with 0 = m + p^+.
Assume m < n implies some p with n = m + p^+ and
show if m < n^+, then some p with n^+ = m + p^+.
Thus by induction is a proof of the question.